# Finding region where $f(z)=e^{-x}\cos(y) -ie^{-x}\sin(y)$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

The text I'm using asked me to find on what region $f(z)=e^{-x}\cos(y) -ie^{-x}\sin(y)$ is analytic. So solving the appropriate Cauchy-Riemann Equations.
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=-e^{-x}\cos(y)=e^{-x}\sin(y)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-e^{-x}\sin(y)=-(-e^{-x}\cos(y))=\frac{-\partial v}{\partial x}
\end{align}
tells me that the region in $\Bbb{C}$ that satisfies those equations consists of complex numbers $z=x+iy$ such that $y=\frac{3\pi}{4}+k\pi$ where $k\in\Bbb{Z}$. But, to me these are points with no neighborhood of differentiable points and makes $f$ nowhere analytic. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the function?

Comment: it's in the title of the post.

Comment: Yes, I know that, But detail the question in Body too. It is in laTex in Tittle(In SE App)

Comment: There, I added the function in body of the post.

Comment: Thanks a Lot.  TheLast Cipher :)

Comment: no problem. please help. thanks :)

Comment: I think you are correct.

Comment: Both your partial derivatives of $v$ are wrong (you seem to have switched them). The function $f$ is analytic everywhere.

Comment: @user567182 Why mislead the OP?

Comment: @GonzaloAlejandroBenavidesGa Why mislead the OP?

Comment: @Did: Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$. 
$$
e^{-x}\cos(y)-ie^{-x}\sin(y) = e^{-x}(\cos(-y)+i\sin(-y)) = e^{-z} 
$$
So $f(z)=e^{-z}$, which is entire.